# Multi-threaded server and workflows with big bottlenecks

Tags: library, java, server

I'm looking at a challenging design problem.  I think I could invent a way to solve it, but I want to see if there's any existing libraries out there so that I don't have to reinvent the wheel.

We're running a server, written in Java, that processes large numbers of requests.  The server is running on a fleet of hosts, and there's a thread pool on each host.  Processing each request consists of executing steps S1, S2, S3, ..., S*n*.  Not every step is needed for all requests, and which steps are needed can't be determined up front--that is, the result of S*k* may determine whether some later steps are needed.

The issue is that certain steps (let's say S2 and S4) require significant delays--possibly as much as an hour.  (In our case, they call downstream services that put low limits on the request rate.  We could also imagine a case where they call downstream services that simply take a very long time to complete.)  What is happening is that if we simply let the thread wait until it can continue, we quickly reach a point where all threads on all hosts are blocked, and then no requests can be processed.  Since a large fraction of the requests do *not* need to execute S2 and S4, this is a problem because those requests, which could be processed very quickly, cannot start.

I've been thinking about possible solutions, such as having a Java abstract class to define a "step", and some kind of controller that has a list of steps, and will execute a sequence of steps on a thread until it hits a blocking point, at which point it would relinquish the thread, and the controller would either hold onto the context information in an in-memory queue so that it can restart the sequence on some other thread when it becomes unblocked; it's also possible that there might be too many requests even for an in-memory queue, so an external queue might be needed.  I can imagine a few possible architectures, but I haven't tried to devise any details for any of them yet.

But before I do, I'd like to know if there's some off-the-shelf Java library to solve this sort of problem.

(I'm not looking for a rate limiter; we already have leads on that.  I'm looking for a way to manage the workflow in a way that doesn't block threads when a rate limiter is in use or other very long delays are possible.)

Answer (score 1):

How is the thread currently blocked? Are you in a loop waiting for some information to come? Are you checking on some information on a regular basis until it changes its state?

From what I understand I would suggest an [open source scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_job_scheduler_software).

Comment: Our current implementation uses [Guava RateLimiter](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html).  Its `acquire()` method blocks until a permit is available, but I have no idea how it does the blocking.  Thanks for the link, I'll take a look.

Comment: I'm not sure to fully understand the function but I'll look into it, you got me interested. On the other hand, I had a similar issue using an external service. The [PEPS](https://peps.cnes.fr/rocket/#/home) platform is doing processing in the background and I'm using a loop in ActiveEon's solution to ask on a regular basis when the file is available. In that case, my resources are free between the different requests and can be used for other purposes.